# Swift Date Formatting returning Nil

Tags: swift, datetime, date-formatting

I'm trying to set a label to a formatted date string on Sign Out press.

```
let dateFormatterUK = DateFormatter()
let dateString : String = String(describing: Date())
dateFormatterUK.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
let currentDateTime = dateFormatterUK.date(from: dateString)
```

Above is my code formatting the `Date`. When I set my label to the `currentDateTime` variable however, it is set as `Nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
let dateFormatterUK = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterUK.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
let currentDateTime = dateFormatterUK.string(from: Date())
```

And If your date is in String and want to change format:

```
let dateFormatterUK = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterUK.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

let stringDate = "11-03-2018"
let date = dateFormatterUK.date(from: stringDate)!

// set new format
dateFormatterUK.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let currentDateTime = dateFormatterUK.string(from: date)
```

Comment: @benjiiiii, You should accept it as an answer if your problem fixed. :-)

Comment: Hey, sorry I was just waiting till it would let me accept it :)